# Xamarin for Android - not getting correct size image from resource folders

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

As a newcomer to Xamarin I have created an app which has a landing page with a few images.

I placed the different sized images in the relevant drawable folders within resources, but no matter what size of device I test on for Android, the default image is always picked up.

I was under the impression (maybe wrongly) the Android can determine the correct resource to use, so other than setting the image source in my XAML page, is there any other 'wiring up' I have to do to get the correct image?  Also, the text does not resize either, but at a guess that's because I set the font size manually?

--EDIT--

```
below is the content from the XAML



 <ContentPage.Content>
            <!-- MAIN WRAPPER -->
            <Grid>
                <!-- ICON BACKGROUND -->
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="150" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <StackLayout Padding="0,0,0,380" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" x:Name="logoStack">
                    <Label Text="" />
                    <Image x:Name="logo" Source="MyLogo.png" 
                           Grid.Row="1"
                        HorizontalOptions="Center"
                        Aspect="AspectFill"
                        VerticalOptions="Center" 
                           />
                    <Label Text="" />

                </StackLayout>

                <StackLayout Padding="0,110,0,0" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" x:Name="imgStack">

                    <Image
                    x:Name="img"
                    Grid.Row="2"
                    Source=""
                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                        Aspect="AspectFill"
                        VerticalOptions="Center"
                    />
                </StackLayout>

                <Grid 
                    Grid.Row="0"
                    Padding="0"
                    Margin="0,30,0,0"
                    VerticalOptions="Center" >

                    <!--FIRST LEVEL ELLIPSIS-->
                    <Label
                        Style="{DynamicResource WalktrhoughItemTemplateShape}" 
                        FontSize="360"
                        />

                    <!--SECOND LEVEL ELLIPSIS-->
                    <Label
                        Style="{DynamicResource WalktrhoughItemTemplateShape}" 
                        FontSize="260"
                        />

                    <!--SECOND LEVEL ELLIPSIS-->
                    <Label
                        Style="{DynamicResource WalktrhoughItemTemplateShape}" 
                        FontSize="180"
                        />

                    <!--ICON BACKGROUND-->
                    <Label
                        Style="{DynamicResource WalktrhoughItemTemplateShape}" 
                        FontSize="130"
                        Opacity="0.3"
                        />

                    <!--ICON-->
                    <Label
                        x:Name="IconLabel"
                        Style="{DynamicResource WalkthroughStepIconStyle}"
                        VerticalOptions="Center"
                        Text="{ x:Static font:GrialShapesFont.LogoGrial }"
                        />

                </Grid>

                <!--TEXT -->
                <StackLayout x:Name="headerStack"
                        Grid.Row="3" 
                        Padding="20, 40, 20, 0"
                        VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                    <Label 
                        x:Name="HeaderLabel"
                        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" 
                        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                        Text="" 
                        FontSize="22" 
                        FontFamily="Helvetica Neue"

                        TextColor="#E9F2F8"/>
                </StackLayout>
                <StackLayout x:Name="txtStack"
                        Grid.Row="4" 
                        Padding="20, 0, 20, 0"
                        VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                    <Label 
                        x:Name="DescriptionLabel"
                        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                        Opacity="0.7" 
                        Text="" 
                        FontSize="14" 
                        FontFamily="Helvetica Neue"
                        TextColor="#E9F2F8"/>
                </StackLayout>

                <StackLayout Grid.Row="5" x:Name="sIndicator"
                        Padding="20, 25, 20, 0"
                        Spacing="0"
                        >
                    <Image
                    x:Name="indicator"
                    Source=""
                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                        Aspect="AspectFill"
                        WidthRequest="140" 
                        HeightRequest="10"
                        VerticalOptions="Center"
                    />
                </StackLayout>

                <!--BUTTON-->
                <StackLayout  Grid.Row="6" x:Name="sButton">
                <artina:Button 
                    Grid.Row="6"
                    Margin="20"
                    Style="{DynamicResource PrimaryActionButtonStyle}"
                    x:Name="PrimaryActionButton"
                    BackgroundColor="#FFFFFF"
                    TextColor="#2980B9"
                    VerticalOptions="End"
                    Command="{Binding LoginPageRedirect}"
                    Text="Login"/>
                </StackLayout>
                <!--BUTTON-->
            </Grid>
        </ContentPage.Content>
```

thanks

Comment: Can you show how exactly you added the different sized images and how your code looks like? It should work...

Comment: Have included the XAML in an edit, the images were added by resizing according to this ratio: mdpi- 1X
hdpi- 1.5X
xhdpi- 2X
xxhdpi- 3X